# How to reference the implementing class from an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, interface

I'm creating an interface where I need a method to reference a class instance of the class that implements the interface. Here is an example:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface{
    public void MyMethod(MyClass a){...} //implemented from the interface.
}
```

So how should I implement my interface (without generics) to reference the class that it is implemented in?

```
interface IMyInterface{
    void MyMethod(??? a);
}
```

What should come to the `???` part?

Thanks,
Can.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that? Why don't you want to use generics?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you tell us for *which* purpose you need an interface like this?

Comment: posted as a comment to the answers below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The C# type system isn't sophisticated enough to represent the notion of a "self" type well. IMO, the ideal solution is to abandon this goal and just depend on the interface-type:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void MyMethod(IMyInterface a);
}
```

If this insufficient, it is often suggestive of the interface being poorly specified; you should go back to the drawing board and look for an alternative design if possible.

But if you still *really* need this, you can use a (sort of) C# version of the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
interface IMyInterface<TSelf> where TSelf : IMyInterface<TSelf>
{
    void MyMethod(TSelf a);
}
```

and then:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface<MyClass>
{
    public void MyMethod(MyClass a) {...}  //implemented from the interface.
}
```

Note that this is not a completely  "safe" solution; there's nothing stopping an evil implementation from using a different type-argument:

```
class EvilClass : IMyInterface<MyClass>  // TSelf isn't the implementing type anymore...
{
    public void MyMethod(MyClass a) {...}  // Evil...
}
```

which works against your goal.

Comment: but i've said, i need a way to accomplish this *without* generics, if possible. the first one is closer but wouldn't work as i need an explicit type name there.. it will be used in an inheritance situation, and type casting etc will make my code writing both harder and error prone

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu: Sorry, but the C# type-system isn't strong enough to represent the notion of a "self" type. There's no other option that I know of.

Comment: ok, if its just impossible, then i'll go with your way.. thanks

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu, if you tell us why exactly do you think you need this, maybe we could help you better.

Comment: @svick too long to put the whole thing here, but i'll try to explain it in a simple manner:

i'm making a game where objects have this hierarchy. GameObject<-PlatformObject<-PlatformDynamicObject (that can move). i've got template classes for each, to read from the resource and build a template, and they act as factories for that class type. i have this IObjectTemplate<T> interface where T is the exact type to return, and there is the CreateNew method that returns a T based on the data in the template, and template classes also have a similar inheritance and i was trying to sort it out.

Comment: Then generic interface as suggested by Ani seems to be the way to go to me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `IMyInterface` instead of `MyClass`. It will be able to accept anything that is derived from and using that interface. If you don't want this for whatever reason, still do it, but add some other "check" to the interface, something like `public bool IsValidParam()` or whatever. In general I'd consider something like this bad design (interfaces shouldn't depend on any implementation of that actual interface other than stuff provided in the interface itself).

Comment: it will work technically, but the interface will be implemented differently through generics (for something else) from classes in an inheritance hierarchy and typecasting will mess things up

Comment: Still wouldn't advice it. Is there some specific scenario or reason for doing it that way? If there's some param that is specific to one implementation or more implementations, I wouldn't add it to the generic interface.

Comment: no, nothing type speficic. there is just too much inhertance in the system, with all implementing a generic interface already, i just didn't want to make things more complicated. so it's a "purification of code" reason, not a "technical reason"

Comment: So guess you don't want to use the interface for the parameter's type due to using something of the implemented class? As it's getting dirty anyway, you could simply use `object` and cast it in the implementation. You won't have type checks that way, but might make it easier to use then restructuring all instances where the interface is used.

Comment: i actually need a nice way to "chain" this scenario: there is type hiearchy, and they have their corresponding "template" classes that act as factory, and for each template, i simple build a mechanism that will take an object of the target (fixed for the template type) type and copy template properties into it, and the derived template will simple create its own target type, pass it to base template class' same method to fill it in, and then add it's derived specific fields, there are several ways to accomplish this, and im looking for the best one and thought it'd be easy in such a way.

Comment: Ew... not sure if I understood you correctly, but sounds like either calling the constructor of the base class or using the generic IInterface for the parameter type would be a lot easier. To be specific: Specialized class would call base class's constructor or base class's generic `MyMethod(this)` or whatever.

Comment: yes, i'm going somewhere like that.. but slightly different, gave up the impossible and implemented with two generic arguments to the interface, one the type that it creates, and one itself, and i get the desired functionality. it would be syntactically better to be able to get along with no self reference, but it was not possible.